# Docker Error: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: line 7: /usr/local/bin/env2yaml: cannot execute binary file

Tags: docker, powerpc

I am trying to build a logstash 7.6.0 image using centos:7 as the base image On PPC64LE architecture.

```
FROM centos:7
COPY bin/docker-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/
COPY env2yaml/env2yaml /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint"]
```

The image was successfully built, however it gives the following error:

```
[root@p006vm32 logstash]# docker run -it logstash:7.6.0
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: line 7: /usr/local/bin/env2yaml: cannot execute binary file
```

Docker:

```
Client:
Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   ccde200
 Built:        Tue Jun  5 20:32:10 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/ppc64le
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   ccde200
  Built:        Tue Jun  5 20:35:04 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/ppc64le
  Experimental: false
```

Comment: What kind of a file is `env2yaml`? [How can I resolve the error “cannot execute binary file”?](https://superuser.com/questions/435988/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-cannot-execute-binary-file)

Comment: I am using all files from https://github.com/elastic/dockerfiles/tree/7.6/logstash

Comment: Try adding execute permission for `env2yaml` file - `RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/env2yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Given [env2yaml](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-docker/blob/master/build/logstash/env2yaml/env2yaml.go) is a go executable its assumed you have compiled this to a ppc64le executable.

After that enable execute permissions by including this in the Dockerfile after the `COPY`

```
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/env2yaml
```